# Error using gsutil in Github Actions workflow (with google-github-actions/auth): Cant issue ID_TOKEN for job in Completed state

Tags: google-cloud-platform, github-actions

I have these steps:

```
jobs:
  build-and-test:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    permissions:
      contents: read
      id-token: write

    steps:
      - name: Check out
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - id: auth
        uses: "google-github-actions/auth@v1"
        with:
          workload_identity_provider: ${{ secrets.GCP_WORKLOAD_IDENTITY_PROVIDER }}
          service_account: ${{ secrets.GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT }}
          token_format: "access_token"
```

And they complete without errors.

Then, later in the workflow, I try this:

```
      - name: Download test data
        run: |
          mkdir -pv ${MY_VAR}
          gsutil -m rsync -r gs://some-bucket/some-folder ${MY_VAR}
```

But that fails with this error:

```
google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: (
  'Unable to retrieve Identity Pool subject token',
  '{
     "$id":"1",
     "innerException":null,
     "message":"Can\'t issue ID_TOKEN for job in \'Completed\' state.",
     "typeName":"GitHub.Actions.Runtime.WebApi.CannotGenerateIdTokenException, GitHub.Actions.Runtime.WebApi, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
     "typeKey":"CannotGenerateIdTokenException",
     "errorCode":0,
     "eventId":3000
   }'
)
```

The value of `secrets.GCP_WORKLOAD_IDENTITY_PROVIDER` and `secrets.GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT` seem correct to me. I've read https://github.com/google-github-actions/auth/blob/main/docs/TROUBLESHOOTING.md and have made sure that they look as they should.

When I try to do the gsutil command manually, using the same service account (as the value of `secrets.GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT`), then that works without issues.

Any suggestions for things I can look into to figure out why this isn't working?

Edit to update my working theory:

- My current theory is that there's a lingering key that's "active" in some sense, from running https://github.com/google-github-actions/auth previously
- That "active" key is for a previous github actions workflow run which is completed, and thus it no longer works.

How can I confirm this? Why is `gsutil` trying to use outdated keys, when the auth step should've created a new key?